# Why is the author using a double colon in this vim command?

Tags: vim

I'm doing a [Vimgolf problem](http://vimgolf.com/challenges/56fb2e75ccffcc0009026473) to transform this:

```
- One number per line -
-----------------------
2,3,5,7,
11,13,17,
19,23,29,
```

to this:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
```

One solution is

```
::%s/,/\r/g|v/\d/d<CR>ZZ
```

I understand most of this command but I have a few questions:

1) Why is there an extra colon `:` in front of `:%s`?

2) What is `|v/\d/d` doing?

Comment: I looked on that page and I can't find any solution with multiple colons. Are you sure you typed it correctly? Aslo FWIW, their solution is wrong, there must be a `<CR>` between the last d and `ZZ`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Colon**

This is more of a typo. It doesn't mean anything but it still works the same as single colon

**2. `v` command**:

```
v/\d/d
```

This is just the second command [`:vglobal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:v) which will remove all the lines `/d` which don't contain a digit `\d`. It's a negation of `g` command - [`:global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:g)